# Grids from every tick in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot

By using the following code:

```
plot(covcomp$MeanCoverage, 
     covcomp$MeanKbCov, 
     yaxs="i", yaxp=c(0, 40, 40), 
     panel.first=grid(equilogs=TRUE), las=2)
```

I get this plot:

[image]

I would like to get grids attached to every tick on y axis. Not only every tenth. If I add `grid(NA, 12, lwd = 1)` than there will be grids all over depending on the amount of grids I put in there but not synchronizing with the ticks.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw the grid by hand, with `abline`, whose `h` and `v` arguments also let you draw horizontal and vertical lines.

```
abline(h=0:50, v=c(0,5,10,15), lty=3, col="lightgrey")
```

Comment: Very kewl. Didn't know you could do both h and v in same call.